# Access jQuery component within Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, nouislider

I am completely new to Vue and I'm having trouble reading a variable from a jQuery plugin. I am using a plugin called nouislider because I need two handles and I can't dynamically out the values with a computed method:

```
    <div id="app">
        <div  id="slider"></div>
        <div>{{perc}}</div>
    </div>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        perc: 0,
      },
      watch: {
        percentage: function(){
          this.perc = tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.get();
        }
      }
    })

    var tooltipSlider = document.getElementById('slider');

    noUiSlider.create(tooltipSlider, {
        start: [50, 70],
        margin: 1,
        range: {
            'min': 1,
            'max': 99
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I recommend you use a vue slider component here. Your watchers need to have the same name as the watched data properties.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/ktsn/vue-range-slider Also you need to understand that watchers are for watching data properties in your Vue viewmodel (the object you pass to `new Vue()`), not for watching ouside stuff.

Comment: but I can't have two handles with this slider

Comment: You should avoid using jQuery with Vue; there are some conflicts behind the scenes.

Comment: @LachlanShoesmith Disagreed. It's perfectly fine to use jQuery alongside vue; it just need some form of adaptation where you put the jQuery initialization stuff in the `created()` hook of your vue VM.